# React Native Search Bar with search engine

Tags: react-native, searchbar

I created my first public github repo with some open source, where I created a Search Bar with a search engine. I did it with the intention of saving people's time and helping them.

I need your help improving this repo, because I've never published a code in Github before, also, is the code generic? Any suggestion is welcome.

here's the link: https://github.com/AissaRouk/React-Native-Search-Bar

Thanks in advance :) !!!

Comment: If you are asking for people to review your code, maybe it is more appropriate to post on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is not a programming QUESTION and it does not belong on SO. Abra made a good suggestion.